# to_param not working in nested polymorphic associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This test is failing at the line `get_users_path`:

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @admin = users(:user_baz)
  end

  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    .
    .
  end
end
```

Here is the error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'callsign' for nil:NilClass
        app/models/user.rb:35:in 'to_param'
        app/views/users/_user.html.erb:3:in '_app_views_users__user_html_erb___623096829469928541_2227766840'
        app/views/users/index.html.erb:8:in '_app_views_users_index_html_erb__62429272046032246_2224894860'
        test/integration/users_index_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'`
```

It's referring to the line `self.character.callsign` in the `to_param` method in the User model.

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  has_one  :character, as: :sociable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :character
  has_secure_password
  before_validation do
    self.create_character unless character
  end
  before_save do
    self.email.downcase!
  end
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name, presence: true,
                   length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
  validates :character, presence: true

  def to_param
    self.character.callsign
  end
  .
  .
end
```

Character.rb:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sociable, polymorphic: true 
  before_save do
    self.callsign.downcase!
  end
  VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX = /\A[a-z\d\-.\_]+\z/i
  validates :callsign, presence:   true,
                       length:     { maximum: 20 },
                       format:     { with: VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX },
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

app/views/users/index.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

app/views/users/_user.html.erb:

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for_user user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Why is this test failing? Why is `self.character.callsign` in `to_param` not working?

Comment: It seems that the `character` relationship is not assigned. Since it's a required validation, maybe that model isn't saved. Verify that first.

Comment: i think your self object is nil so u can debug the code using pry and pry-rails gem. after adding this u just need to write `binding.pry` above the ` self.character.callsign`

Comment: Actually the character didn't exist, see my answer.
Thank you for alerting me to pry, that's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I hadn't manually given a character to all the users in test/fixtures. In characters.yml I created a character for every user, and the test passed.